# How to upgrade a Visual Studio Project from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 (VS 2010 to VS 2012) - For WebParts, MasterPage, AppPage, User Controls

Tags: web-part, custom-masterpage, sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2012, user-controls

We have a SharePoint 2010 project solution which we are trying to uprgade to SharePoint 2013. This includes webparts, application pages, user controls, masterpage, etc.

Foll. is the procedure we follow, please add to it/comment if we have missed out anything:-

1. Open your project solution file by right clicking and choose open with VS2012.
2. Edit your .csproj file and add to it -> `<TargetOfficeVersion>15.0</TargetOfficeVersion>`
3. Go to VS2012 and reload you project, Go to project properties and set framework as 4.5
4. Go to package and under properties of the package set the version to 15.0
5. Do a find replace for 14.0.0.0 to 15.0.0.0.
6. Check each file to do a check for any hive references. You'll need to add a /15/ to these. EG: _layouts/ to _layouts/15/ and also for CONTROLTEMPLATES
7. For master page project make sure you copy paste the SP2013 seattle masterpage from Designer and use it in VS project.
8. If you are using AJAX control toolkit then make sure you use version 3.0.30930.28736 as this worked well. If we tried using AJAX version 4.5 then the webparts do not work when deployed.
9. Do right click on project and Click Clean to clean solution
10. Build the solution, then Deploy your projects.

Please add to this if there are more points to be considered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got most of the things covered even though steps 2, 3 and 5 need not be manual. If you have latest version of Visual Studio 2012 / 2013 and Microsoft Office developer tools installed, the project will be automatically upgraded.However you can double check after the code is upgraded. Once you perform all the above steps and deploy the WSPs to test environment you need to check each functionality of your solution. What breaks or works depends on the functionality in the solution. This step obviously varies for each upgradation. I have put my findings here. http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2013/12/sharepoint-2013-upgrade-sharepoint-2010.html

Comment: Thats a fantastic article! I wish I had landed on it before breaking my head on upgrading..

Comment: Blame search engines for not putting it up there or my lack of proper keywords/title.

Comment: Nadeem, how do I check if I got latest version of VS2012 and office dev tools?

Comment: The latest update for VS 2012, Update 4 is present here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305 Also you can install office dveloper tool for VS 2012 using Web Platform Installer http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx.

Comment: I have got the VS2010 soln with me. Also got latest versions of VS2012.. Now how to automatically  cover steps 2, 3 and 5 ?

Comment: Just open the SP 2010 solution in VS 2012 and it will ask if you want to upgrade the solution and click on Yes as shown in the blog post.